# JSOUP- Trying to find a specific a href

Tags: java, jsoup

[image]

I am trying to find the circled link as seen in the image above at imgur on a webpage.Currently(as seen below) I am just pulling all a hrefs from the document and looping through it looking for the one that contains "pdf" as it is the only one on the page,is there any way to just pull a href where title = "Download offers in store" or something like that

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.dunnesstores.com/offer20/food-wine/fcp-category/home").get();
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]" + );

for (Element link : links) {
    System.out.println(link.attr("href"));
    if (link.attr("href").contains("pdf")){
        pdfLink = link.attr("href");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could specify a selector that matches a attribute and its value.

```
String pdfLink = null;

Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.dunnesstores.com/offer20/food-wine/fcp-category/home").get();
Elements links = doc.select("a[title=\"Download offers in store\"]");

for (Element link : links) {
    pdfLink = link.attr("abs:href");
}

System.out.println(pdfLink);
```

This selects every a tag where the title attribute is equals Download offers in store.

If you want to search the element by the file ending .pdf you could change the selector to:

```
a[href$=".pdf\"]
```

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

```
doc.select("a[title='Download offers in store']");
```

> [attr] Represents an element with an attribute name of attr.
>
> [attr=value] Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and
>   whose value is exactly "value".
>
> [attr~=value] Represents an element
>   with an attribute name of attr whose value is a whitespace-separated
>   list of words, one of which is exactly "value".
>
> [attr|=value]
>   Represents an element with an attribute name of attr. Its value can be
>   exactly “value” or can begin with “value” immediately followed by “-”
>   (U+002D). It can be used for language subcode matches.
>
> [attr^=value]
>   Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose first
>   value is prefixed by "value". 
>   [attr$=value] Represents an element with
>   an attribute name of attr and whose last value is suffixed by "value".
>
> [attr*=value] Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and
>   whose value contains at least one occurrence of string "value" as
>   substring.